# return value after complete the forloop in nodejs and javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have this function for return array of string .

```
 async GetAllPermissonsByRoles(id) {
    let model: string[] = [];
    try {
        id.forEach(async (role) => {
            let permission = await RolePermissionModel.find({ roleId: role._id })
                .populate({
                    path: 'permissionId',
                    model: 'Permission'
                });
            permission.forEach((elment) => {
                model.push(elment.permissionId);
            });
        })
    } catch (error) { }

    return model;
}
```

but i have a problem with this code , in this function not wait for complete `forLoop` and then `return model` , loop is not complete yet but returns the value .

**whats the problem ? how can i sovle this problem ?**

**Update :**

i write this code but still have that problem :

```
  async GetAllPermissonsByRoles(ids) {
    let model: string[] = [];
    try {

        await Promise.all(ids.map(async (role) => {
            let permission = await RolePermissionModel.find({ roleId: role._id })
                .populate({
                    path: 'permissionId',
                    model: 'Permission'
                });
            await Promise.all(permission.map(async (permission) => {
                permission.forEach((elment) => {
                    model.push(elment.permissionId);
                });
            }))
        }))
    } catch (error) { }

    return model;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use forEach with async/await. Please read this as explanation [async await with forEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Comment: @kianoushdortaj you don't need second ```await Promise.all``` you just need to go through the permission, because you only need to await for getting from the database -> RolePermissionModel and then you do iteration through the result